# Unable to record from USB sound card line-in connector

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been googling and struggling with this for a while but haven't been able to make this work.
I bought a USB sound card ([Encore ENMAB 8-CM](http://www.encore-usa.com/mz/product/ENMAB-8CM)) to record from its line-in connector.

I'm not sure which input to pick in Audicity, but I'me sure I've tested them all. [These are all the available inputs I have in Audacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59oBy.png).

But there's no sound being recorded at all.
I've already checked the device is working, so I really don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Also, I have Alsamixer like this (http://imgur.com/IdKVoMD). I have Pulseaudio volume control like this in inputs tab (http://imgur.com/impR9Dg). And like this in recording tab when Audacity is recording (http://imgur.com/5UoAgXB).

Comment: Oh, I forgot, using Linux Mint 17 MATE.

Answer (score 0):

In alsamixer, "PCM" is muted; unmute it.
"IEC958" is the digital input; disable it.
I don't know why "PCM Capture Source" is a check box; try both settings.

Comment: Thanks for the info about IEC958, I disabled it. I unmuted PCM and tried both with and without "PCM Capture Source" option, but neither the pulse nor the default devices in Audacity seem to get any reaction at all.

Also, so far it works on a Win XP VM in the same machine. So I can be sure there's nothing wrong with both devices working together.

Comment: I could see that ignoring all ALSA, Pulseaudio and stuff, I see no movement in the sound settings volume bar when I play something in the line-in input. This makes me think it is related to something in a lower layer. Maybe a module that needs to be loaded or something. I really know little about that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the alsamixer on terminal?
Your alsamixer has too few settings.

[Screenshot of alsamixer in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkoSN.jpg)
Also, disable automute feature.

Comment: Yup, found that digging a little bit more into this, but no luck. I noticed though that I get no signal whatsoever from the external card's line-in in Linux; I do get from the virtual WinXP in Linux. Maybe a drivers matter?